# RIP Colin Cantwell

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Concept artist [Colin Cantwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Cantwell) has passed away at the age of 90. Cantwell contributed to films including *2001: A Space Odyssey*, *Close Encounters of the Third Kind*, and *WarGames*, and also wrote two sci-fi novels, but his biggest and most famous contribution to sci-fi was to *Star Wars*.

Cantwell provided the initial designs for many of the film's most iconic vehicles, including the Death Star, the Imperial Star Destroyer, the X-Wing and Y-Wing, the TIE fighter, the *Tantive IV*, the landspeeder, and the Jawa's sandcrawlers. He also helped to devise the iconic opening scene of the *Tantive IV* being pursued by a Star Destroyer.

> The beginning of the film after the scroll, the ship coming by was like one giant dart. It kept coming and it kept coming. Then it had a hatch on the bottom and things kept coming out of the hatch, but this was only halfway. Then the stern came up and it had the same exaggeration. This is what had to compound itself in the first ½ hour of the film. It had to be all so absurd and different and insanely joyous and perilous that the audience wouldn't leave. They would want to be in it. The first half hour had to be extraordinarily successful and beyond reason.
> <sub>*~[Colin Cantwell, on the opening scene of Star Wars (1977)](http://www.cantwellcollection.com/interviews.html)*</sub>

Cantwell was also a real-world scientist who worked at NASA during the Apollo program, and assisted Walter Cronkite during his broadcast of the Apollo 11 moon landing.